# How to calculate the prediction power of each independent variable on a new data frame

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to calculate the prediction power of each independent variable.I have a training data frame named `df` and the test data frame named `df1`. I wrote a code that should append the prediction results based on each cloumn as part of the test data frame.My code give a strange result: It presents only one variable's prediction results and without its name.I would like to see all variables predictions and their names too.I'm new to function writing so any help is welcome.

```
df <- read.table(text = " target birds    wolfs     
                            32         9         7 
                            56         8         4 
                            11         2         8 
                            22         2         3 
                            33         8         3 
                            54         1         2 
                            34         7         16 
                            66         1         5 
                            74         17        7 
                            52         8         7 
                            45         2         7 
                            65         20        3 
                            99         6         3 
                            88         1         1 
                            77         3         11 
                            55         30         1  ",header = TRUE)

df1 <- read.table(text = " target birds    wolfs     
                            34         9         7 
                            23         8         4 
                            43         2         8 
                            45         2         3 
                            65         8         3 
                            23         1         2 
                            22         7         16 
                            99         1         5 
                            56         17        7 
                            32         8         7 
                            19         2         7 
                            91         20        3 
                            78         6         3 
                            62         1         1 
                            78         3         11 
                            69         30         1  ",header = TRUE)
```

Here is the code that I use

```
for(i in names(df))
     { 
             if(is.numeric(df[3,i]))  ##if row 3 is numeric, the entire column is 
                 {       
                         fit_pred <- predict(lm(df[,i] ~ target, data=df), newdata=df1)

                             res <- fit_pred
                         g<-as.data.frame(cbind(df1,res))
                         g
                     }
         }
```

The output that I got is :

```
 userid target birds wolfs   res
10    321      45     8     7  0.0515967
8     608      33     1     5  0.1696638
3     234      23     2     8  0.1696638
7     294      44     7     1  0.0515967
2     444      46     8     4  0.0515967
11    226      90     2     7  0.1696638
9     123      89     9     7  0.0515967
1     222      67     9     7  0.0515967
5     678      43     8     3  0.0515967
15    999      12     3     9  0.1696638
6     987      33     1     2  0.1696638
14    225      18     1     1  0.1696638
16    987      83     1     1  0.1696638
12    556      77     2     3  0.1696638
```

Comment: Hi, your presented output doesn't match the input/code you've given so I'm not sure what the desired output is. However, your loop keeps overwriting its results, so you only keep results from the last iteration.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka, I fixed the problem but how can i prevent the loop to keep overwriting itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a `for` loop here. You should one of the `xxapply` family functions. Here the R-way to do this:

```
fit_pred <- function(x)predict(lm(x ~ target, data=df), newdata=df1)
do.call(cbind,lapply(df,fit_pre))
```

1. I wrap your code in a function
2. I use `lapply` to loop over all the columns
3. `do.call` and `cbind` toi aggregate the result

Comment: Thanks @agstudy for your answer.There is a typo in your answer: should be fit_pred) at the end of line two.I used for loop here in order to learn to work with this kind of function.I've a question regarding your answer:If I would like to check the predictive power of two variables for example How can I do it using your code structure?

Comment: @mql4beginner it is not clear what do you want to check. Here we vary the response variable  not the predictor. Do you want to have 2 predictors variables at each step? you should look at `mapply` and maybe at combn. In fact you need to generate all pairs.

Comment: @agstudy, yes I would lke to check for  2 predictors variables at each step or to  generate all pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is a process that uses packages dplyr and tidyr, in order to create models based on y~x combinations (the dependent variables you specify ~ the independent variables you specify) and then use those models to predict new data.

The idea behind it is that both y and x variables might change (even if here you have only "target" as y). I'm using the dataframes df and df1 you specified in the beginning (I don't know why "target" becomes binary in your output).

Run the process step by step to see how it works and modify it to better fit your objective.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# input what you want as independent variables y and dependent x
ynames = c("target")
xnames = c("birds","wolfs")


###### build models

# create and reshape train y dataframes
dty = df[ynames]
dty = dty %>% gather(yvariable, yvalue)

# create and reshape train x dataframes
dtx = df[xnames]
dtx = dtx %>% gather(xvariable, xvalue)

# build model for each y~x combination
dt_model =
    dty %>% do(data.frame(.,dtx)) %>%         # create combinations of y and x variables
      group_by(yvariable, xvariable) %>%      # for each pair y and x
      do(model = lm(yvalue~xvalue, data=.))   # build the lm y~x

# you've managed to create a model for each combination and it's stored in a dataframe
dt_model

#   yvariable xvariable   model
# 1    target     birds <S3:lm>
# 2    target     wolfs <S3:lm>



####### predict

# create and reshape test y dataframes
dty = df1[ynames]
dty = dty %>% gather(yvariable, yvalue)

# create and reshape test x dataframes
dtx = df1[xnames]
dtx = dtx %>% gather(xvariable, xvalue)


dty %>% do(data.frame(.,dtx)) %>%            # create combinations of y and x variables
  group_by(yvariable, xvariable) %>%         # for each pair y and x
  do(data.frame(., pred = predict(dt_model$model[dt_model$yvariable==.$yvariable &         
                                                 dt_model$xvariable==.$xvariable][[1]]))) %>%     # get the corresponding model and predict new data
  ungroup()

#    yvariable yvalue xvariable xvalue     pred
# 1     target     34     birds      9 54.30627
# 2     target     23     birds      8 53.99573
# 3     target     43     birds      2 52.13249
# 4     target     45     birds      2 52.13249
# 5     target     65     birds      8 53.99573
# 6     target     23     birds      1 51.82195
# 7     target     22     birds      7 53.68519
# 8     target     99     birds      1 51.82195
# 9     target     56     birds     17 56.79059
# 10    target     32     birds      8 53.99573
# 11    target     19     birds      2 52.13249
# 12    target     91     birds     20 57.72220
# 13    target     78     birds      6 53.37465
# 14    target     62     birds      1 51.82195
# 15    target     78     birds      3 52.44303
# 16    target     69     birds     30 60.82760
# 17    target     34     wolfs      7 51.49364
# 18    target     23     wolfs      4 56.38136
# 19    target     43     wolfs      8 49.86441
# 20    target     45     wolfs      3 58.01059
# 21    target     65     wolfs      3 58.01059
# 22    target     23     wolfs      2 59.63983
# 23    target     22     wolfs     16 36.83051
# 24    target     99     wolfs      5 54.75212
# 25    target     56     wolfs      7 51.49364
# 26    target     32     wolfs      7 51.49364
# 27    target     19     wolfs      7 51.49364
# 28    target     91     wolfs      3 58.01059
# 29    target     78     wolfs      3 58.01059
# 30    target     62     wolfs      1 61.26907
# 31    target     78     wolfs     11 44.97669
# 32    target     69     wolfs      1 61.26907
```

Comment: Thanks , what is the meaning of yvariable, yvalue ? should I supply them in advance?

Comment: No. The process gets them automatically via the gather command. The only specification you do is the beginning (ynames and xnames). If you run the process step by step you'll see those things.

Comment: You can modify the final output (dataframe) if you want, but right now it tells you that the first 16 rows are predictions of "target" using "birds" based on a model like lm(target~birds). The other 16 are predictiond of "target" using "wolfs" based on a model like lm(target~wolves).